# Sorting pictures with matching dates into galleries

Tags: php, variable, loop

I am attempting to build galleries of photos based on {photo_date}, a custom field containing the date on which each photo was taken. My list of photos looks something like this:

```
Photo#   {photo_date}
1        11/1/14
2        11/1/14
3        11/1/14
4        11/16/14
5        11/16/14
6        11/22/14
```

My goal is to have a loop that allows only one photo to appear from each date "group." This photo will serve as the photo group's cover image. So, after running the script, I will end up with  this:

```
Group 1: Photo#1 (11/1/14)
Group 2: Photo#4 (11/16/14)
Group 3: Photo#6 (11/22/14)
```

I am attempting to use a php variable inside of an EE loop to check to see if it matches:

```
           <?php $clip = "0"; ?>
           {exp:channel:entries channel="event_photos" dynamic="no" sort="asc" orderby="photo_date" search:photo_date="not IS_EMPTY"}
            <div class="clear floatnone">
                {if "{photo_event}{photo_event:url_title}{/photo_event}" == "<?php echo $currentSegment; ?>"} <!-- filter only this event's photos -->
                    Before add: <?php echo $clip; ?><br />
                    {if "{photo_date format='%m/%d/%y'}" != "<?php echo $clip; ?>"}
                        {title}<br />
                        <a href="{photo}" data-lightbox="{photo_date format="%m/%d/%y"}" data-title="{photo_caption}"><img width="150px" src="{photo}" /></a>
                    {/if}
                    <?php $clip = "{photo_date format='%m/%d/%y'}"; ?>
                    After add: <?php echo $clip; ?><br />
                {/if}
            </div>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

I think this should work, but it doesn't. It seems that the PHP variable ($clip) is getting assigned at the end of the {if} loop, but gets erased at the beginning once the loops starts over. This prevents me from checking to see if the {photo_date} in question has been used or not in the previous iteration. I'm wondering how to get the variable to retain the intended value?

I appreciate any thoughts or maybe a more elegant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just using Channel Images?

Comment: I don't have access to the Channel Images module right now. Do you have another suggestion? :/

Answer (score 0):

OK - so after reading this a few more times I think I have a clearer sense of what you may be doing.

If you're relating the event photos in one channel to events in another (I'm guessing this based on your [{photo_event}{photo_event:url_title}{/photo_event}] code, I think I'd do it the other way.

Start by running a query to select the date in question - use select distinct (or the  :[activerecord plugin](https://github.com/rsanchez/activerecord) )
Then relate that date to your photo and limit the relationship field to one result (try limit="1") in the tag. That should give you your dates with an image for each to correspond - with no php in your templates.

Also - not sure what/why that $currentSegment is in your code, but maybe check out [Segment variables](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/url_segments.html) for what you need there?

If this is off base, then I still don't get what you're trying to do. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the [Stash add-on](https://github.com/croxton/Stash). There's an example in the docs called [Sort a list of entries by year and then by month](https://gist.github.com/croxton/6219973). You could use a simpler version of that example for your needs.

I created an example that doesn't include all of your HTML markup and custom fields (photo, photo_caption, etc.). But this should get you started.

Step by step it works like this.

First, set a list of all your entries:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="entries" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:channel:entries channel="event_photos" dynamic="no" sort="asc" orderby="photo_date" search:photo_date="not IS_EMPTY"}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:date_sort}{photo_date format="%m/%d/%y"}{/stash:date_sort}
        {stash:date_machine}{entry_date}{/stash:date_machine}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Make a copy of the same list containing only the `date_sort` dates (mm/dd/yyyy) so we can find all unique dates:

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="dates" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:stash:get_list name="entries"}
      {stash:date_sort}{date_sort}{/stash:date_sort}
  {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Then output the list of unique dates and a list of entries that match that unique date. The `date_machine` is used to order them within each unique date.

```
{exp:stash:get_list name="dates" unique="yes" orderby="date_sort" sort="desc"}

  <h1>{date_sort}</h1>

    {exp:stash:get_list:entries 
        name="entries" 
        match="#^{date_sort}$#" 
        against="date_sort" 
        orderby="date_machine" 
        sort="asc" 
        prefix="entry"
    }

      {if entry:count==1}
      <ul>
      {/if}

      <li>{entry:title} ({entry:date_sort})</li>

      {if entry:count==entry:total_results}
      </ul>
      {/if}
    {/exp:stash:get_list:entries}


{/exp:stash:get_list}
```